# How can I order a cloud firestore snapshot with 2 fields?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to order a cloud firestore snapshot with 2 fields. I'm using flutter/dart
I have this error :
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'lenght' was called on null.  Receiver: null. Tried calling: length. See also: https//flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors.

I'm using cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0

My code:

```
  Stream<List<Friend>> getFriends() {
    return _db
        .collection('profile')
        .doc(userId)
        .collection('friends')
        .orderBy('status', descending: true)
        .orderBy('displayName', descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => Friend.fromJason(doc.data()))
        .toList());
  }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of query you do (ordering on two fields) **is** supported on Firestore, but does require an index that is not automatically created.

If you check the debug output of your app, you should find another error message when this query runs. In this error message there is a link that takes you to the Firebase console with all the information already filled in. From there it takes a single click to create the index, and make the query work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just Add Your Index Query. Here is the Example : Please Check . it will take 2-5 minits to Build the index query . after that you will be able to see like this .

Note : If you use VS Code , go to Debug/Terminal You will find out the direct link via clicking this link indexs query will **auto generate** for you . link will redirect you to the Firestore indexes console